# Notification badge counter disappears on dismissing the notification

Tags: notifications, android-11, redmi, notification-badges, miui-13

> Device : *Redmi Note 11* (*MIUI 13.0.10.0* with *Android 11*) using the default launcher

**Problem:** Whenever a notification gets dismissed (even without opening it) the badge counter attached to the respective app disappears.

The badge counter will remain visible on the app icon as long as the notification is not dismissed from the notification area.

**Expected behaviour:** This is a common behaviour to keep the badge counter visible on the respective app if there are any unread notifications, but this is not happening.

**Question:** Is this a bug? Is there a way to keep the badge counter visible on the app even after dismissing the notification from the notification area?

Comment: AFAIK, unlike the implementation of custom badges provided on some launcher apps, this is how the native Android notification badge works: dismissing the notifications will also dismiss the badge.

Comment: @AndrewT. Really?? I used to think otherwise for my entire life 